# A monospace font with unicode glyphs

Tags: fonts, glyphs

I'm looking for a monospace font which has a lot of the unicode glyphs. In particular I'm interested in the speaker symbols, code points 1F507 to 1F50A.

Comment: what about using iconic fonts such as fontello? http://fontello.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ferdi. Unfortunately I have to use the same font for both symbols and text in my particular use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a modern solution:

Check out [The JuliaMono Typeface](https://juliamono.netlify.app/).

IMHO it looks way better than Everson Mono, and it has very good Unicode support.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if the speaker would be included, but have you tried [**GNU Unifont**](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)? It is **monospaced**, it comes in `TTF` and it covers glyphs for every printable code point in the Unicode 6.3 Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). I do think, however, that it's a bitmap font.

You can see the [**insanely huge list of covered glyphs here**](http://unifoundry.com/gnu_unifont-6.3.20131221.png).

---

[**Monospace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospace_%28Unicode%29), on the other hand, is based on Georgia and covers 2,862 glyphs. Apart from the languages, it includes:

> General Punctuation, Superscripts and Subscripts, Currency Symbols,
>   Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols, Letterlike Symbols, Number
>   Forms, Arrows, Mathematical Operators, Miscellaneous Technical,
>   Control Pictures, Enclosed Alphanumerics, Box Drawing, Block Elements,
>   Geometric Shapes, Miscellaneous Symbols, Alphabetic Presentation
>   Forms, Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms.

Comment: Thanks for those two suggestions. The coverage of the GNU Unifont is indeed impressive but it lacks the symbols I'm looking for. I've already tried Monospace.

Comment: @Yisela the vectorized version [lacks many glyphs](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57352) compared to the original version. Also I don’t remember of a monospace version of ɢɴᴜ unifont.

Comment: Downside is this font is really ugly. It's very pixelated and basically only suitable when the text is (very) small.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileInfo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f507/fontsupport.htm) to check which fonts support character U+1F507 or other characters. Maybe you will find the font you're looking for.

I found this one which looks great and has many glyphs though the ones you're interested in are not included : [Everson Mono on FileFormat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/eversonmono/index.htm) or the [original web page](http://www.evertype.com/emono/). I have counted 8835 glyphs but FileFormat mentions 9756 of them.

Please note that this is a shareware:

> Everson Mono is shareware. If you use it, support its development by buying a licence to do so. The shareware fee for using one or more than one (that is, any or all) of these Unicode-supporting coded font programs is €25.00. The licence gives you the right to use these fonts on three CPUs and three CPUs only. (That’s two at the office and one at home, so please don’t complain.) Shareware is not freeware. You may not use Everson Mono for free.

Comment: It looks like a nice font but lacks the specific glyphs I'm after.

Comment: Sorry, I will update my answer